# SQL dynamic File Name in Subscription

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have SQL, and SSRS reports. I have a subscription on the report server. I am trying to execute this subscription via a SQL script and change the file name dynamically.

Is there a way that when a job is called, you change the file name? Is there another way to go about this? Can a file location in which it will be stored once executed be changed as well?

My SQL Code

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = N'5789A36B-5657-2255-A765-dCX7F2D83932'
```

My subscription in Reporting Services (File Name is PurchaseOrders. Can this be dynamically altered? Can the Path??)

[image]

Comment: what version of report services do you have? Is it Standard or Enterprise?

Comment: It is standard edition.

Comment: You are pretty limited with standard edition.. I don't think you can change names dynamically at run time.. only Enterprise edition can do this with Data Driven Subscriptions

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction